I want to add bar codes to certain output fields in my sportfire report
Spotfire- I want to add bar codes to certain output fields in my spotfire report but cannot find how to do this using standard spotfire, I don't want to write a script to do it.
I would like the output to look like :
Part number bar code           qty      bar code for qty
ABC 1234       [ BAR CODE]     10       [10]
Thank you for any help in advance

Please provide a data sample and specify where this bar code comes from. E.g. another dataset, a formula?

Hi, thank you. The data comes from a dataset within the report.  Really I just want a bar code font in spitfire, is this possible do you know ?
Tony

If you google "bar code printing in spotfire" you get some "google AI" tips but I have no specific experience in that. I thought you wanted to add some actual column values.

Ahh ok thank you. I will give it a go.
